# How bad is the word "pussy"?

Tags: offensive-language

I know words, I have the baddest words, but I'd like to know exactly how bad the word "pussy" is. When it's referring to women's genitalia, and when the word is being discussed as opposed to used, how much is it censored? Is it enough to put it in quotation marks, or does it get its vowels asterisked and/or get the "f word" treatment?

Comment: Why not ask this question on EL&U?

Comment: @Mari-Lou an English-learner is apparently avoiding using the word, and I want to know whether they're justified in doing so.

Comment: All of the above: see [this](http://money.cnn.com/2016/10/07/media/vulgar-comments-donald-trump-headlines/index.html). The 'p-word' isn't quite so abrasive as the 'c-word', but it's bad enough.

Comment: Unless the objective is to outrage someone, the term should be used only (and unambiguously) in reference to a feline. The sole exception, to my mind, is its use in an intimate setting between sex partners.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/80919

Comment: Related (EL&U) [How does “pussy” come to mean “coward”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100990/how-does-pussy-come-to-mean-coward) and [Use of 'pussy' as term of endearment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347426/use-of-pussy-as-term-of-endearment) and [Is there an American English equivalent for the British “moggie”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287623/is-there-an-american-english-equivalent-for-the-british-moggie-for-a-non-pureb)

Comment: It is a 7.8 on the badness scale, per the International English Advisory Board.  But seriously, the answer depends on the context.

Answer (score 3):

The use of the "p-word" varies based on social context, audience, period in history, and various other factors.  Originally "pussy" simply meant "cat" and something like, "Poor pussy! Let's get you some milk" wouldn't seem out of place in any children's story. Of course these uses seem unintentionally risque *now*, but when they were written there was nothing wrong with them.

[The court is out on exactly when "pussy" became synonymous with the female pudenda](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-etymology-of-the-word-pussy-as-a-synonym-for-vagina), but given its frequent use in periodicals and the like it was probably not until fairly recently, and then only as a vulgar term that might have been *known* but was not used by "decent folk".  Since then its use has become more commonplace and far less obscene, but it can still be very offensive when it's meant to reduce a woman to a object of sexual satisfaction.

In some cases the feminist movement has co-opted the term and made it their own, for example the all-female band ["Pussy Riot"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pussy_Riot) or a recent book ["PUSSY: A Reclamation"](http://a.co/8un57sF).  In this context it's not at all offensive and indeed deliberately satirical of those who try and use it to demean women.

Another use of "pussy" is as an insult to a male by implying cowardice.  It can be a relatively strong pejorative, but probably far from the *worst* thing you could say to many men, and is often no more than *teasing* to coerce someone into doing something they consider scary or dangerous.

But to turn to current events:  When someone like Donald Trump says it, even though it was years ago, the particulars of his conversation make it pretty severe.  I don't know of any women who aren't *extremely* offended by what he said. In this context it is on par with "fuck" and most newspapers and family-friendly periodicals will substitute asterisks (p***y), if they print it at all.

Edit: Relevant story on CNN: [The 'p-word' problem: Trump's comments pose issue for news outlets](http://money.cnn.com/2016/10/07/media/vulgar-comments-donald-trump-headlines/index.html?iid=surge-story-summary)

Comment: As a note, it's not uncommon for comedians to use "pussy" intentionally for comedic double entendre. See the character Mrs. Slocombe from the 70s-80s British comedy show *Are You Being Served?* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRJlItzalJY

Comment: @Catija that was back in the day when *pussy* was relatively "rude", nowadays with hard core porn on the Internet 24/7 it would be too risque to say on any family TV show, which *Are you being served?*, was. It all depends on context, calling someone a pussy (a coward) I find to be a relatively mild offense. Asking a lady who is carrying a cat in its cage "Can I stroke your pussy?" to be worthy of a loud *groan*, but then again, it would depend on *how* it was said. It could sound positively creepy and intimidating and vulgar, said by a leering man. And that is why the question is POB.

Comment: @Mari-LouA not quite sure the point of your comment. I didn't make any assertions in regards to "family friendliness". I said comedians use is as double entendre and gave an example. Most comedians I've seen, in fact, aren't family friendly.

Comment: @Catija AYBS was a family show, even children used to watch the show. Today's comedians who might use the word *pussy*, I don't think British comedians do as a matter of fact, are directed toward the adult public. Today *pussy* is not "rude", it errs on  vulgar, nasty and tacky.

Comment: @Mari-LouA As you said, it's opinion... personally, I would have no issues with someone using "pussy" the same way it's used in AYBS... I find it really funny and have absolutely no issues with it... clearly that's because I grew up watching the show.

Answer (score 0):

### cat

I would recommend that the OP's friend (see comments) use the expression **pussycat** (one word) if he ever wants to refer to a cat affectionately. It used to be also a coquettish name for a girlfriend, back in the day, but I don't hear it anymore. I suppose that is a strong indication that the term pussy is generally perceived to be vulgar.

Tom Jones had a 1967 hit with the song "[What's New Pussycat?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBdSqk78nHw)", a delightful and catchy tune it is, too.

Listening to the song again,  I hear the lyrics, *I'll soon be kissing your sweet little pussycat lips*... erm... err... *Who* would ever say that nowadays?

### genitalia

(*Cunnilingus* is sometimes referred to, vulgarly, as *“eating pussy”*)

How times change.

### nickname

There was an Italo American mobster in the TV American show, *Sopranos*, whose nickname was [Big Pussy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Pussy_Bonpensiero) he earned the title because he started his career as a *cat burglar*.  I don't know if any American viewer actually protested to HBO, but the character was a big hit with fans around the world.

### To sum up

How bad is the word *pussy*?

Pretty bad, if anyone was mildly shocked by the terms I used in the answer, I think that is sufficient proof.

Comment: I didn't know that terms could be coquettish.

Comment: @TRomano term, ... romantic name, term of endearment , affectionate term, ... where's the problem?

Comment: If you think this is primarily opinion based, you shouldn't be answering it.

Comment: @Catija true, I had cast a vote saying it was POB, but this morning I saw the question was still opened, and someone had answered it. No, correction, two other users had answered. So, too late to delete the question I thought to myself, ‘I'll leave a comment’. The comment was too long, so I posted an answer. and because I dislike hypocrisy, I retracted my VTC. I think this question should have been posted on EL&U but ELL can't migrate questions to EL&U. And twice my requests to migrate two separate questions to EL&U have been declined.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why do you feel this would be better on EL&U? How offensive certain terms might be to native speakers is [right in our wheelhouse](http://www.chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2013/09/09/in-ones-wheelhouse-from-boats-to-baseball-to/) in my opinion. (I wasn't involved with your migration flags, so this is just curiosity and not debating).

Comment: @ColleenV  It's not about offensiveness, it's that I believe this type of question is better suited to users on that site. The question is not geared towards learners but to native and advanced speakers. Well... EL&U has an abundance of those.

Answer (score -2):

Really informal and disrespectful. 
But it's okay if you say it to a cat

> Hey, pussy pussy cat

Comment: There really isn't enough explanation to make this a good answer. Please explain the answer and why it is correct.

Comment: +1 for reminding about the word *pussycat*.  But in your example it would simply be: "Here, pussy, pussy." and then making the appropriate cat calling sound by pursing your lips and kissing loudly.